# Ubuntu 22.04 - guest additions CD, shared clipboard, shared folder do not work

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, clipboard, shared-folders, copy-and-paste

I had a VM with Ubuntu 21.04, I deleted it and I have made a new VM with OS Ubuntu 22.04.

On the previous OS, I was used to enable:

- **Guest additions CD**: from menu devices>insert guest additions CD -> this enabled screen enlargment with right <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- **shared clipboard**: devices>shared clipboards>bidirectional -> this enabled copy&paste from my host to my virtual machine and vice versa.
- **shared folder**: devices>shared folders>settings> various choices -> this enabled file transfer from my host to my virtual machine and vice versa.

I did the same on the new VM with Ubuntu 22.04, rebooted various times from OS menu, but the changes do not take place:

- right <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> changes only the VM window size, but does not enlarge the screen.
- Copy&paste does not work from my host to my virtual machine (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>) and vice versa (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>).
- the shared folder I configured is not present at path `/media/`

What could be the cause of it? How can I solve it?

### UPDATE

The Guest additions CD / screen size point is SOLVED.
I solved by setting the hosted OS screen resolution to the desired size from OS menu settings>displays>resolution>(put the same resolution of my host OS).

Though, have created a new VM and installed ubuntu 21.04 and did the same configuration operations that I did for Ubuntu 22.04.
For Ubuntu 21.04, it is not necessary to set the size resolution from the OS settings menu to make the screen enlargement via right <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> work.
Furthermore, in Ubuntu 21.04 it is sufficient to run the operations that I have described upwards to make the shared folder and shared clipbord work.

I also deleted the VM with Ubuntu 22.04, generated a new VM, installed the 22.04 OS again, and still I get the same problems.
Maybe something is wrong with my Ubuntu 22.04 iso:
**ubuntu-22.04-desktop-amd64.iso** - 3.569.249 KB - from https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/

Comment: Is your version of VirtualBox fully updated? An out-of-date VirtualBox may cause this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED

It turns out that on Ubuntu 22.04 the process of installing the  VirtualBox Guest Additions is a little bit more manual than the one I rmembered for Ubuntu 21.04.

First I have updated Virtualbox from 6.1.22 to 6.1.38:

- close all the processes and then shut down the VM.
- update virtualbox
- restart the PC
- start virtualbox and the VM

Then run

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

From the VirtualBox topbar menu: **Device** > click on **Insert guest additions CD**

create a folder where to place the installation content

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/cdrom
```

Mount the CD

```
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

run the installation software in the mount

```
cd /mnt/cdrom
sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
```

Reboot the VM

```
sudo reboot
```

The quickest way to check if the installation worked is to test the screen enlargment, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(right) +<kbd>F</kbd>